# Can one use potential wind power to transport on Shabbos?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, weather, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Would it be permitted to set a cart with a sail in a reshus hayachid with the intent that if the wind picks up, it will carry the contents 1) into a reshus harabbim, or 2) through a reshus harabbim and into another reshus hayachid?

Comment: Is there wind currently blowing? If not it would seem to only be a grama.

Comment: Note also that if there is no hanacha in the reshus harabbim then it is not a biblical violation.

Comment: Aaron, in light of @DoubleAA's previous comment, I would suggest you edit your question to refer to a case where the wind simply transfers the item from a reshus hayachid to a reshush harabim.

Comment: The reason I chose to have it land in a reshus hayachid is that it seemed like it would be a more practically useful place for the contents to be, but I would be interested in either case.